# How to refer to the log4j properties from external place

Tags: properties, log4j

Is there a way to refer the log4j property file from an external place.

Example: Keeping the file in one location and using that in java classes.

Thanks and Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a tremendously lazy question, Use the property configurator.

Reggards,
Hari

Comment: No its not about your english, Dont ask simple question. Cross your barrier by googling.

Comment: sorry i want fast anser